WebSocket session using org.springframework.web.socket vs org.springframework.web.reactive.socket
I have a working WebSocket session based on org.springframework.web.socket where the method handleTextMessage is overridden and receives the payload successfully
When trying to do something similar based on org.springframework.web.reactive.socket (sample code here
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webflux-websocket.html#webflux-websocket-client); I don't receive any data.
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.socket.client.ReactorNettyWebSocketClient;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.socket.client.WebSocketClient;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @SpringBootApplication
    class Test implements CommandLineRunner {

        @Override
        public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
            WebSocketClient client = new ReactorNettyWebSocketClient();

            {
                try {
                    URI url = new URI("ws://localhost:8080/path");
                    System.out.printf("Starting Session");
                    client.execute(url, session ->
                            session.receive()
                                    .doOnNext(System.out::println)
                                    .then());
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Note: ws://localhost:8080/path works well as I have already tested the feed works fine in Postman and also using org.springframework.web.socket
